# Using excel indirect to get data from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

can anyone please explain what this indirect is pointing at ?

```
=@INDIRECT("'High Level'!T"&$AO33)
```

that not being A033

High Level is one sheet and the expression above is in another sheet.

thanks

Comment: What's in cell `AO33`?

Comment: it actually is AO33 not A033 ... so what cell would that be ?

Comment: Only you can tell what is in cell `AO33`... we can't bc we don't have your workbook.

Comment: it's showing something all right

Comment: But that still begs the question what is in cell `AO33`?

Comment: It may be helpful to use Formulas > Evaluate Formula here.

Comment: This thing is concatenating the string `High Level!T` with whatever is in your cell `AO33`, likely that cell contains a number and this string would look something like `High Level!T1`. Indirect then pulls the value from worksheet `High Level` cell `T1`. If `AO33` changes to `2` then Indirect updates the cell in which this formula is contained to pull the value from worksheet `High Level` cell `T2`.

Comment: @JNevill i will mark your answer as what I wanted if you write that in a answer. I came to understand that indirection while or before you wrote it as a comment. thanks

Comment: I think you captured well in your answer and I have plenty of points already. Glad that helped connect the dots :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it and I will write the explanation if someone wants to understand something similar:

suppose you have 2 sheets: "High Level" and "Sheet1" and you see a value in sheet1 that you want to change but you only see the below formula:

```
=@INDIRECT("'High Level'!T"&$AO33)
```

that can be translated to:

goto sheet called : "High Level",
(the **!** tells us it is another sheet)
place yourself on column **T**,
and  (**&**),
search for whatever row it is indicated in your current sheet's column **AO**  and row **33**.

$AO33 is a mixed reference which basically means: $ says the column **AO** will always be fixed but the row number **33** may change.

Comment: INDIRECT being volatile will recalculate ar any change within the workbook **anywhere**. Since the sheet name is always the same, you could avoid that with the use of INDEX: `=INDEX('High Level'!T:T,$AO33,)` would achieve the same, but is not volatile.